# Updating model's FileField manually in django views

Tags: django

I have a csv file stored in a model's FileField. I want to drop selected columns from the csv file and update the file stored in the Project's FileField.

I have successfully retrieved the file from the model and stored it into a Pandas DataFrame. Selected columns are successfully dropped from the dataframe BUT failed to UPDATE the file stored in the Project's FileField.

Here is my model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    base_file = models.FileField(upload_to='project-files', default=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is the view that suppose to manipulate the file through pandas dataframe:

```
def PreprocessView(request, **kwargs):
    proj_pk = kwargs.get('pk')

    project = Project.objects.get(id=proj_pk)  
    df      = pd.read_csv(project.base_file)
    n_cols  = df.keys

    context ={}
    context['df']     = df
    context['n_cols'] = n_cols

    if request.method == 'POST':       
        checked_values = request.POST.getlist(u'predictors')
        str_check_values = ', '.join(checked_values)
        df.drop(columns=checked_values, inplace=True)
        new_df = df.to_csv(project.base_file.name)
        project.base_file = new_df
        project.save()

        messages.success(request, f'{str_check_values} has been successfuly removed!')

    return render(request, 'projects/preprocess/preprocess.html', context)
```

The following lines returns an error and failed to update the File in the database.

```
        new_df = df.to_csv(project.base_file.name)
        project.base_file = new_df
        project.save()
```

Comment: what's the error? show us full trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a file object and then attach it to model. Like this

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile


if request.method == 'POST':       
    checked_values = request.POST.getlist(u'predictors')
    str_check_values = ', '.join(checked_values)
    df.drop(columns=checked_values, inplace=True)
    new_df = df.to_csv()

    updated_file = ContentFile(new_df)
    updated_file.name = "filename.csv"

    project.base_file = updated_file
    project.save()
```

Comment: not correct. `new_df = df.to_csv(project.base_file.name)` is `None` (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)). But without the error I'm not sure if the problem is saving `None` or changing the file in place when calling `to_csv`.

Comment: also when changing a file like that, you should probably cleanup and delete the old file.

Comment: @dirkgroten IMHO you are not correct. It can return something. Please check at the end of doc you attached. And in this case it does return csv contents I just tested with a model instance.

Comment: “If path_or_buf is None, returns the csv as string, otherwise returns None”. Since it’s not none (it’s set to project.file.name), it should return None.

Comment: @Nafees Anwar I modified the ```new_df = df.to_csv(project.base_file.name)``` with this ```new_df = df.to_csv()```. Notice I removed the to_csv()'s parameter. Then, added the ContentFile you suggested and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.to_csv()` returns `None` if you give it a file path to save to. So `new_df` is `None`.

You don't need to do anything after you did `df.to_csv(project.file.name)`, the file is already changed.